# How to remove message event handler in javascript. Event not closing and duplicating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a script for a custom menu with clickable buttons that can be used for either opening new windows with new buttons or placing functions behind buttons for playing music in-game etc.

The problem I am facing is that whenever you close the menu by clicking on the "Close" button and opening the menu again, the event is executed twice. When you repeat this, it happens 4 times, then 8, and so on. It seems that it "add event handler" is not closed and when the menu is opened again, a new handler is created. Now we have all these events running, and doing the same thing duplicating everything.

This is the code from Javascript.

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {

  MenuName = event.data.MenuName
  MenuTitle = event.data.MenuTitle
  MenuOptions = event.data.MenuOptions

  if (MenuName == 'MainMenu') {
    $('#npc-header').html(MenuTitle);
    for (let i = 0; i < MenuOptions.length; i++) {
      if (i <= 6) {
        $("#option" + i).show();
        $("#option" + i).html(MenuOptions[i].Title);
        $(document).on('click', "#option" + i, function() {
          if (MenuOptions[i].Type == 'Menu') {
            if (MenuOptions[i].Title == 'Settings') {
              $.post('https://DokusCore--Menu/OpenSettingsMenu', JSON.stringify({}));
            };
            if (MenuOptions[i].Title == 'Functions') {
              $.post('https://DokusCore--Menu/OpenFunctionsMenu', JSON.stringify({}));;
            };
            if (MenuOptions[i].Title == 'Music') {
              $.post('https://DokusCore--Menu/OpenMusicMenu', JSON.stringify({}));;
            };
          } else if (MenuOptions[i].Type == 'Option') {
            if (MenuOptions[i].Title == 'Open Inventory') {
              $.post('https://DokusCore--Menu/Close', JSON.stringify({}));
              $('body').fadeOut();
              $.post('https://DokusCore--Menu/OpenInventory', JSON.stringify({}));
            };
          };
        });
      };

      if (i < 6) {
        for (let i = MenuOptions.length; i < 6; i++) {
          $("#option" + i).hide();
        };
      };
    };
  };

  if (MenuName == 'SettingsMenu') {
    $('#npc-header').html(MenuTitle);
    for (let i = 0; i < MenuOptions.length; i++) {
      if (i <= 6) {
        $("#option" + i).show();
        $("#option" + i).html(MenuOptions[i].Title);
        $(document).on('click', "#option" + i, function() {
          if (MenuOptions[i].Type == 'Menu') {

          } else if (MenuOptions[i].Type == 'Option') {

            if (MenuOptions[i].Title == 'Toggle Music') {
              $.post('https://DokusCore--Menu/ToggleMusic', JSON.stringify({}));
            };

          };
        });
      };

      if (i < 6) {
        for (let i = MenuOptions.length; i < 6; i++) {
          $("#option" + i).hide();
        };
      };
    };
  };


  $('body').fadeIn();
});

// Close the menu
$(document).on('click', ".btn-closeinterface", function() {
  $('body').fadeOut();
  $.post('https://DokusCore--Menu/Close', JSON.stringify({}));
});
```

Does anyone have an idea how to close this event whenever the user clicks on the close button?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In plain js you can use [`removeEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) to achieve the opposite effect that `addEventListener()` has.

In jQuery, the [`off()`](https://api.jquery.com/off/) function seems to serve a similar purpose as `removeEventListener()`.

In both cases you will need to give a name to your callback functions instead of using anonymous functions as `removeEventListener()` and `off()` receive the event handler function as a parameter.

Comment: I tried this method, but jQuery does not seem to know that the off() does. But i am looking further into it and it seems that the event itself is not called upon double each time when the menu opens. It seems to happen after the for() loop indexing the menu buttons. from that moment on I start to see log message double. I think I have to re-write the whole script and index the buttons only one, then later just call upon them using switch and cases.

Comment: Oh, I see. The re-write route may be a better choice. Good luck!